# GZip Footer Regeneration

Tags: .net, gzip, file-format

I have a system which uploads documents, running them through GZip and storing them on the server. A bug in the code caused the GZip header to be overwritten in the files by setting the stream position to 0 before the write content was flushed, overwriting the header.

I've created a program to insert the header in the files that are missing it, but i'm unable to unzip the file as the footer no longer matches.

Is it possible to correct the file footer from this state? I had assumed that I could just add the 10 byte header to the original documents, the checksum was for the file body, and the footer was the total file length, so I could just increment the counter by 10.

All help appreciated, as these files are quite important.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Following the advice of Iain, i've tried decompressing the body of the zip file using the Deflate algorythm. The code is as follows:

```
    private void DecompressStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Copy everything but last 8 bytes
            CopyStream(input, memStream, 8);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            using (var deflate = new DeflateStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                //Now try to decompress the stream
                deflate.CopyTo(output);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output, int dropBytes)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            var lastMessagePart = (input.Position == input.Length);

            //Might go negative - to fix.
            if (lastMessagePart)
                read -= dropBytes;

            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

There is an exception at the deflate.CopyTo(output) line, which fails with: Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.

UPDATE 2:

Alright! I've fixed it. The loss of the first 10 bytes didn't actually change the content of the stream or the footer. So just adding it back in again caused it to work. There was a small bug in my memory stream logic that meant it didn't work when I fed it straight into the GZip decompression, but when I output it to disk and read it back in, it worked fine.

Thanks for all the help guys, you got me looking at it from a different angle.

UPDATE 3:

Alright, I haven't fixed it. I've got a fix for small files, but larger ones seem to be causing problems still. I'm going to continue investigation and maybe i'll be able to figure out a solution.

Comment: How do you know you only overwrote the gzip header?  You should not be modifying the gzip trailer.  The length there is not the length of the gzip file, but rather the length of the uncompressed data.

Comment: Please provide the first 100 bytes of an example of an overwritten gzip file in hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you should be able to decompress without the footer, as long as you ignore the CRC check and length check. IIRC, the gzip footer size is the *uncompressed* size `mod (2^31)-1`

I'm not sure you will be able to rebuild a correct footer without decompressing, as you will need the original data to do the CRC check. You shouldn't need to hold all the decompressed data in memory.

In .Net, you can use the `deflate` stream instead of `gzip`, then you don't need the header or footer, which you can rebuild. If there is any data corruption, you will have no way of knowing.

[Deflate Stream (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Iain, thanks for the quick reply. I'm copying the content to a memory stream, stripping off the last 8 bytes, and then trying to deflate - but i'm getting the following error: Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.

Comment: Possible, but remember that the deflate stream *doesn't* have the gzip magic number either. You will have to skip the first 10 bytes of your stream before passing to the deflate stream. The first bits should be one of 000, 001, 010; Anything else means corruption.

Comment: Do i need to add the magic number to the top of the file in order to run the DeflateStream? All the existing files which can be unzipped (via GZip) start with { 31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0 }. None of my broken files have this.

Comment: No, you need to *not* have the header. gzip is `header` + `deflate` + `footer`. If the header is missing, and the file still won't deflate then it might be lost. Can you post the first couple of dozen bytes from a broken file in your question?